Inconsistent field mapping after migrate from KMongo to MongoDB Kotlin Driver
I recently migrated my Spring Boot application's dependency from KMongo to MongoDB Kotlin Driver. Here are the individual dependency versions I'm using:

Spring boot/Spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb: 2.7.18
Mongo-Driver-Kotlin-Sync: 4.10.0
Mongobumblebee: 1.2

My model class remained unchanged throughout the migration:
@Model
data class Estatus(
        @field:BsonId
        var id: String? = null,
        val actief: Boolean = true
)

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Model


Previously, with the KMongo dependency, my code looked like this:
val mongoClient = KMongo.createClient(MongoClientURI("mongoUrl"))
val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName")
val collection = database.getCollection("estatus", Estatus::class.java)
collection.insertOne(Estatus(id = "5c18c443230eb7d79ed04222", actief = false))
val eStatusList = collection.find().toList()
assertThat(eStatusList[0].actief).isEqualTo(false) //THIS IS WORKING FINE

However, after migrating to the MongoDB Kotlin Sync dependency, the field mapping seems to have issues:
val codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),                CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
        )
val settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .applyConnectionString(ConnectionString("mongoUri"))
                .retryWrites(true).build()
val mongoClient = MongoClient.create(settings)
val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName")
val collection = database.getCollection("estatus", Estatus::class.java)
collection.insertOne(Estatus(id = "5c18c443230eb7d79ed04222", actief = false))
val eStatusList = collection.find().toList()
assertThat(eStatusList[0].actief).isEqualTo(false) //FAILED
// eStatusList[0].actief always returns true

The problem is that kadasterInzageStatusList[0].actief always returns true, even though it should be false.
I've tried to use codecRegistry to create MongoClient, but it's still not working. I'm seeking a solution to manage this discrepancy in field mapping.
Any insights on why this field mapping discrepancy is happening and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
